# Edit excel file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsx

I'm trying to use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to edit an excel file, but my end file turns out corrupted. My guess is that it is because the file is too complex, but I'm not sure. A very simple excel file works without any problems.

First, PHPExcel reads the file, alters the data and then recreates it right?
It's not just opening and writing to the same file?

I'm getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid cell coordinate (MAX(MATCH(REPT("Z"' in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:594 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php(651):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('(MAX(MATCH(REPT...') #1
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php(624):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::absoluteCoordinate('(MAX(MATCH(REPT...') #2
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Workbook.php(438):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::absoluteReference('(MAX(MATCH(REPT...') #3
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Workbook.php(282):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Workbook->writeDefinedNameForPrintArea(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
>   Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), 0) #4
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Workbook.php(75):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Workbook->writeDefinedNames(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
>   Object(PHPExcel)) #5 /Library/WebServer/Doc in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/sb/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 594

```
public static function coordinateFromString($pCoordinateString = 'A1')
{
    if (preg_match("/^([$]?[A-Z]{1,3})([$]?\d{1,7})$/", $pCoordinateString, $matches)) {
        return array($matches[1],$matches[2]);
    } elseif ((strpos($pCoordinateString, ':') !== false) || (strpos($pCoordinateString, ',') !== false)) {
        throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Cell coordinate string can not be a range of cells');
    } elseif ($pCoordinateString == '') {
        throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Cell coordinate can not be zero-length string');
    }

    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Invalid cell coordinate '.$pCoordinateString); // line 594
}
```

[This is the excel file](https://www.ascap.com/-/media/files/xls/members/payment/cue_sheet_template.xlsx?la=en) I'm using. Ideas?

My PHP code:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

/**
 * PHPExcel
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 - 2015 PHPExcel
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 * @category   PHPExcel
 * @package    PHPExcel
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006 - 2015 PHPExcel (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt    LGPL
 * @version    ##VERSION##, ##DATE##
 */

/** PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

//echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel2007 file" , EOL;
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("templates/Cue_Sheet_Template.xlsx");


echo date('H:i:s') , " Update cell data values that are displayed in the chart" , EOL;
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
/*$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array(50-12,   50-15,       50-21),
        array(50-56,   50-73,       50-86),
        array(50-52,   50-61,       50-69),
        array(50-30,   50-32,       50),
    ),
    NULL,
    'B2'
);*/

// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;


// Echo memory peak usage
echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing file" , EOL;
echo 'File has been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;
```

Comment: ' (MAX(MATCH(REPT("Z" ' looks like the start of some nested functions that aren't being computed. It's supposed to give a row and column coordinate, which means PHPExcel is not being passed the appropriate coordinate. Could you show the line of your code where that gets called?

Comment: Could you show the line in your code that calls this method?
Basically I want to see where $pCoordinateString gets defined. I think I should be able to help because I've used PHPExcel many times in different applications I've made. You probably don't want to change cell.php because it's part of the library and most likely isn't where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT (Original answer below)**

I got a successful result. What I did was copy the content of your xlsx template file. Open a new excel sheet and paste the content from your original template. I removed some of the conditional functions that defined some of the fields and now I get a decent looking result with your formatting in place.

[Here's the preedited file.](http://Here's%20a%20link%20to%20the%20file%20https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvm5qeavlaae6pq/boss.xlsx?dl=1)

[image]

**ORIGINAL**

Sorry this isn't the answer that you want. PHPExcel is failing to parse the print range.

Your solution should lay in redefining your print area into something that PHPExcel can parse, or writing your own custom parser for PHPExcel using regex (ie preg_split) that doesn't simply split the range values.

You're basically taking an excel sheet, inserting values and trying to output a new excel sheet.

If you comment out

`throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Invalid cell coordinate '.$pCoordinateString); // line 594`

then you'll get your new excel sheet with the formatting ruined.

The problem is with your print area

```
A1:A1,0:0,0:0,(MAX(MATCH(REPT("Z":MAX(MATCH(REPT("Z",29):29),B:B,1):1),MATCH(REPT("Z":MATCH(REPT("Z",29):29),C:C,1):1),MATCH(REPT("Z":MATCH(REPT("Z",29):29),L:L,1):1),MATCH(REPT("Z":MATCH(REPT("Z",29):29),M:M,1):1),MATCH(REPT("Z":MATCH(REPT("Z",29):29),N:N,1):1),MATCH(REPT("Z":MATCH(REPT("Z",29):29),O:O,1))):1))),18):18)
```

which PHPExcel decides to explode by the ':' that's right after the 'Z'.

I tried redefining your print area, but haven't been able to. I'm out of time to try this for now. Hope this gets you off in the right direction.

Comment: Cool, that's the first time I get a file out of it! When I try to open the file in Excel I get the message `"Excel could not open test.xlsx because some content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?"` followed by `"Excel repaired or removed unreadable content from this workbook. Do you want to view the log file to see what changed, or delete it?"`. When I open the file it has a lot of `#N/A` which I guess is what you mentioned. This is completely out of my knowledge, but if you have any other ideas I'd really appreciate your help and time. It seems close to working.

Comment: I opened it in Libreoffice without getting messages about repairing, but then it replaces some of the fields with error 507. If you `var_dump($objWorksheet )` you'll see that the print area is what I gave you above. Every file I checked where that print area was more cleanly defined came out exactly like it was supposed to. You'll have to recreate your file and change the print area.

Comment: By recreating you mean alter the original excel file or something in the PHP code? I'm sorry, I'm completely new to this. I found Print Area in Excel and I tried both to clear it and to set it to just the needed fields, but same problem with damaged file and N/A fields. So the PHPExcel is using colons to parse the file and this excel file is having some values that breaks the pattern is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. If you `var_dump($objWorksheet)` and scroll down you'll see that 'printArea' is defined as what I gave above. The nested function give a dynamic print range that PHPExcel is not able to parse. If you could use excel to recreate the sheet with a static print area then it should work normally for you. I'll give it a little more time today.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it another go! If you have some time to give it another stab that's awesome! Here's the same template but with some values filled out if you want something to try it out on: [link](https://www.ascap.com/-/media/files/xls/members/payment/cue_sheet_sample.xlsx?la=en)

Comment: Is it possible to share your file? I just tried to copy everything from the template into a new file. Some things stopped working though, like the original will update the title at the top when changing the program field etc. Also I got the same result when running it through PHPExcel, damaged file and a lot of N/A fields. Which conditions did you change? These files are being submitted to a company, so they can't turn out too different from the originals since I think they're going through an automated system. As long as all the field names are intact I bet it should work. Thank you!!

Comment: Your screenshot looks good. Does this file turn out without any errors for you as well? [link](https://www.ascap.com/-/media/files/xls/members/payment/cue_sheet_sample.xlsx?la=en)

Comment: I removed the dynamic content of the fields when I copied the file. There are links to external files in the original that can't be handled unless they were present in the new folder. It looks for files called Column2, Column3, Column4, etc if you leave it the way you uploaded it. PHPExcel can handle formulas in fields but you'll have to work on the template file to make it compatible.

Comment: I'm just curious, if you give the sample template file (with some content added) the same treatment as you did with the empty template, does it still turn out without any errors? Would be awesome if you could try that! Link to the file again: [link](https://www.ascap.com/-/media/files/xls/members/payment/cue_sheet_sample.xlsx?la=en)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150995/discussion-between-aunt-jamaima-and-seabass).